# Changing the view with my numpad doesnt work anymore as soon when i put my pencil of my drawing tablet

Tags: 3d-view

When I have my pencil near enough on my drawing tablet for it to detect the pencil everything works fine, but as soon as I take it off the tablet an try to change the view with my numpad it doesn't work anymore.

I ether have to put the pencil back on the tablet or move my mouse a bit for it to work again. If I moved my mouse it works until I use my pencil again and put it of the tablet again.